# Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1 on systemctl

Tags: server, services, dbus

I unable to do operation (start, stop service etc) using `systemctl` on server, so that I tring to reinstall `systemd-sysv` packages but still facing same issue with systemctl.

```
root@localhost:~# systemctl daemon-reload
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
root@localhost:~# systemctl start mongod
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
```

D-bus status :

```
root@localhost:~# ps -ef | grep dbus
root      1524     1  0 16:39 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
109       2118     1  0 Jun24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
root      2203 65058  0 17:13 pts/1    00:00:00 grep dbus
root     18311     1  0 Jul22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
```

anyone have idea for this error ?

Comment: Well, do you have `dbus` running?

Comment: @spacelander I update my question,  showing `dbus` running